# Manifold with nonzero pontryagin number?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I am a physics student, for some physical property, I am seeking a manifold with nonzero pontryagin number. And I was told CP(2) is the simplest example which has $p_1(CP(2))=3$.

Is there a nice(nice mean accessible to a non-mathematician) picture to show why this manifold has nonzero pontryagin number? And why a sphere $S^4$ does not. What's special for a complex projective plan. I don't know much about characteristic class.

Forgive me if this question is too naive to mathematicians.

Comment: The sphere is the boundary of the 5-ball, hence 0-bordant. Since Pontrjagin numbers are bordism invariant, this implies p_1=0.

Comment: To compute p_1 you can use the Hirzebruch Signature Theorem which relates the signature to the Pontrjagin numbers. For CP^2, the second cohomology is 1-dimensional and the generator has self-intersection 1, so the signature is 1. 

Comment: The book "Characteristic classes" by Milnor and Stasheff is the classic textbook reference (see Chapter 16 for the Pontrjagin numbers). I don't know about "accessible to a non-mathematician", but it certainly satisfies any other definition of "nice" I can think of. 

Comment: These answers aren't going to be helpful if you don't tell us what you know about Pontrjagin numbers.  For example, what would knowing that $CP^2$ has a nonzero number do for you? 

Comment: @ThiKu, thanks for helping. I've gained more understanding on this issue. I guess the motivation of the question at that time(2 years ago) is to study a topological field theory with local action in the form of Pontryagin classes. And what i was looking for is a 4-manifold which gives nontrivial "action" when evaluate the first Pontryagin class: $[p_1,M]\neq 0$.

Comment: @MarkGrant Thank you for pointing out the nice reference, however, all I found is kind of non-electronic copy of the book. Do you know any better-looking pdf version?

Comment: @RobertBryant thanks for sharpening my question. And see the comments to Thiku for my current understanding. I think the goal for me is to use a 4-manifold with nontrivial Pontryagin number to detect the physical consequence of a topological field theory having terms in the form of $p_1=R \wedge R$, usually we can detect the effect of this action by look at the result when putting this field theory on a manifold with boundary. However, I am curious what if i still put it on a closed manifold but with nontrivial pontryagin number.